# DisplayPort monitors (2) backlights turn on during suspend

Tags: nvidia, xubuntu, display, displayport

When I suspend manually or by timed power management, my two displays turn off correctly, no backlight.

However, at some point the backlights turn back on. If I walk by in the middle of the night, when nobody has been near the computer, I'll have to manually shut off the monitors. The computer is definitely suspended at these times.

This began happening about a month or so ago, I was running Xubuntu 20.10 on an older computer. It worked correctly since I began using this computer, for over a year (no weird backlight during suspend issues).

I just updated to a brand new computer that I built - all hardware is new, except the monitors (identical Dell 27" connected by Display Port) and the graphics card they're connected to (an NVidia Quadro P400).

With the new computer, I installed Xubuntu 21.04 beta, since I didn't want to reinstall again in 2 weeks. Same behavior.

A quirky twist is that occasionally only one monitor has had the backlight lit up...

Using the NVidia driver version 460.67.

Could someone help me troubleshoot this?

Comment: 21,04 is still beta and therefore off topic here.

Comment: Ok, would someone help me debug for my 20.10 computer, which is still here?